# Bounding Box Error in 3D Perception Stack of Autoware.Auto

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was trying to use the `3D Perception Stack` in **Autoware.Auto** to generate bounding boxes and I was facing some errors. Below is the attached rviz2 visualization alongside the simulation.

[image: image description]

In the picture above, the **blue circle represents the bounding box** and the **red circle represents filtered point clouds**. There are two issues that I am trying to resolve:

1. The bounding boxes appear to be **fish-tailing (rotating inconsistently)**. I have tried to change the parameters inside the .yaml configuration (param) files for the `point_cloud_filter` node as well but it does not seem to fix that. I have tried to look at the `.urdf` for the Lexus vehicle for the `robot state publisher` and manipulate the parameters according to how the lidar is configured, but that does not seem to fix it either. This can also be seen in the bounding boxes on the right (trees) which constantly keep changing orientation.
2. The bounding boxes appear to **NOT** line up **longitudinally** with the filtered point clouds. I have **NOT** changed anything in the .`yaml config file for the Euclidean cluster`, so I am confused why the bounding boxes do not line up with the filtered points. I would understand if the filtered points do not line up with the actual object in the simulation (since they can be calibrated using the `sensor_height_m` and the `static transform` parameters) but that is not the case.

The `filtered points` (output of thepoint_cloud_filter node) seem to lineup with the simulation meaning that the translation parameters are somewhat correct.

Let me know why these issues are happening!

Thanks,
Shlok

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372031/bounding-box-error-in-3d-perception-stack-of-autoware.auto/) by [shlokgoel](https://answers.ros.org/users/67161/shlokgoel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, @shlokgoel. To answer your two issues:

1. Given that we are currently only using a naive Euclidean Clustering algorithm, the orientation of the bounding box for each object can change as points are added and removed from the clusters. Frame-to-frame tracking or an ML-based algorithm would be required to better estimate object orientation. Both of these are on our roadmap for the upcoming Cargo Delivery ODD.
2. This is likely due to both lidar processing delays and transform delays. If you change the fixed global frame in rviz to `base_link`, you can offset the second type of delay. Regarding the first, we made a huge performance improvement to the `ray_ground_filter` just prior to the 1.0.0 release Sunday. Please pull the latest `ade` images by adding `--update` to your `ade start` command and test again.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2021-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1